# Minimal-Maximal number of objects in tests; firecrackers in mailbox

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, game-theory, recursion, discrete-optimization

I'm sure this has been asked before *somewhere*, though I do not know the *name* of the problem/algorithm, so here goes.

We are asked to test mailboxes with firecrackers, and find the resistance of a new type of mailbox. We need to find how many firecrackers it can take at once. We are to test with up to $k$ firecrackers, and have $i$ mailboxes for our tests. What is the minimal number of firecrackers you need, to run a test such that you for sure know how many the mailbox can resist? Once a mailbox has blown up, it can't be reused.

I formulate this as $T(i,k) = x$. If $i$ is one, this is just the sum of the integers, since we can't afford to guess, and blow it up accidentally.

**Example**; $T(2,10) = 28$. The optimal place to start is with $7$ firecrackers in the box. If it blows up, we only have one mailbox left, and you have to test from 1 up to 6, hence a sum of 28 firecrackers in total, in the worst case. Looking closely, this is just

$$T(2,10) = 7 + T(1,6) = 7 + \frac{6(6+1)}{2} = 28$$

So we expect some recursion here.
If it didn't blow up, you can reuse it and try with 9, and then in the worst case 10, thus 26 in total, clearly *less*. So, to be completely sure we find the actual resistance, we need $x=28$.

**Q: How can we in general calculate $T(i,k) = x$?** E.g. $T(6,67) = $?

Edit - ***SOLUTION***: Number of tests with $i$ boxes in interval $[k,l]$ (including ends) is

$$T(i,k,l)=\min_n\left(n+\max\left(T(i-1,k,n-1),T(i,n,l)\right)\right)\; $$

Base cases for $i = 1$ is computed as above. If $k+1=l$ we just get $2k+1$. Memorizing the values of $T$ helps the computations go faster. We simply iterate over all possible $n$'s. More base cases are possible, once you start thinking about it, but not necessary.

*EDIT*: Found a link to the problem, and it has a name too https://www.ida.liu.se/projects/progcontest/progsm/2002/prognm2002-hints.pdf.

Comment: Consider $T(i,k,l)$, the minimal number of firecrackers required given $i$ mailboxes and the fact that the resistance lies in $[k,l]$. Then all values can be determined using the recursion

$$T(i,k,l)=\min_n\left(n+\max\left(T(i-1,k,n-1),T(i,n,l)\right)\right)\;.$$

Comment: Yeah, I agree @joriki, and thank you, but how do one decide n in each recursion? There should be some optimal strategy, I presume.

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if there turned out to be a closed formula for that. I think you'll need to solve it with [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) if you're interested in particular values for higher inputs.

Comment: That makes sense, after thinking hard about it. To ease the computations a bit, I am limiting my n to be around the center of mass, e.g. around 7 for k=10, and it seems to work. It's actually for calculating some coordinates to find a geocache:)

Comment: The calculation shouldn't require much easing on a modern computer. The main thing is to [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results so you don't have to keep recalculating them.

Comment: Your are completely right. Thanks!

Comment: This is the *egg dropping problem*, where each mailbox is an egg and each firecracker is a floor in the building.

Comment: Looks similar, but the penalty here is different. No analytic solution here as far as I can see.